# direct hyperlink to compose page of gmail yahoo and outlook

Tags: html, email, hyperlink

I wanted to create hyperlink that will direct it to compose page that similar to Google Mail link (as my example):

```
<li><a href="https://inbox.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=john@doe.com" title="Google Inbox Mail" data-uk-tooltip><img src="mail-google-inbox.svg'; ?>" alt="Google Inbox Mail"></a></li>
```

However, I tried other things but I cannot find same link for Yahoo Mail and Outlook...

Do you have guys idea? Thanks for the help.

**Reason:**

Instead of using "mailto:", we would like to have our users choose which mail program/app to use to compose personal message.

We have alternative options (like modal box with form and/or leave mailto as default hyperlink) but we end up to this flow that we think its good alternative option too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, For Reference of the others... Here's what I have found out. These are the hyperlinks that you can use instead of `mailto:`

**For Google Mail**

`https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=your@email.com`

**For Yahoo Mail**

`https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=your@email.com`

**For Outlook Mail / Hotmail**

`https://outlook.live.com/owa/?to=your@email.com&path=/mail/action/compose`

Comment: I found that it's possible to include `subject` and `body` in the compose URLs. E.g. 
Google: `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=to@email.com&su=Some+subject&body=some+body`
Yahoo: `https://compose.mail.yahoo.com/?to=your@email.com&subject=my+subject&body=some+words+go+here`
Outlook: `https://outlook.live.com/owa/?to=your@email.com&subject=subjects+help&body=body+here&path=/mail/action/compose`